# Are passwords stored in cookies?

Tags: cookies, gmail

Looking at gmail and facebook I was wondering where do they store your password and account info when you log off and you have the function "Keep me signed in" on.

I know they store it in cookies but isnt this hackable/stealable? How safe is this system and where is this information stored?

Answer (score 6):

What they save is a unique session ID that is essentially a randomly generated string. With that session ID they can store your state on the backend, i.e. logged in or not. They never store your password, encrypted or not, in a cookie.